# clicking UIButton?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

is it possible to click UIButton and to call its action through Programming without clicking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just simply call the method associated with your UIButton action as follow :

```
- (IBAction)myMethod:(id)sender {
    // some code here
}
```

When you want to fire an action :

```
[self myMethod:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it programmatically just send a event to button

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess you can get a little help from a friend of mine that help me a lot to get start with objective C and Iphone development Basics. maybe you already have seen him but if not here is the link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B7jB0D3Y7Ws&feature=channel pretty easy to understand.